# Custom Progress drawable for Seek bar not working in Lollipop devices

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I need to use custom gradient file as progress drawable for Seekbar, below is code snippet for the same.

```
<SeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/seek_bar_feeling_right_now"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:max="@integer/check_in_seek_bar_max_value"
                            android:progress="0"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/check_in_progress_drawable"
                            android:splitTrack="false"
                            android:thumb="@drawable/ic_seek_bar_incomplete"
                            android:thumbOffset="0dp" />
```

*** check_in_bg_gradient.xml ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:useLevel="true">

        <gradient
            android:angle="180"
            android:gradientRadius="20dp"
            android:startColor="#ff9898"
            android:endColor="#484c7f"/>

        <corners android:radius="20dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#50999999" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#70555555" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

*** check_in_gradient.xml ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:useLevel="true">

        <gradient
            android:angle="180"
            android:gradientRadius="20dp"
            android:startColor="#ff9898"
            android:endColor="#484c7f" />

        <corners android:radius="20dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#50999999" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#70555555" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

*** check_in_progress_drawable.xml ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/check_in_bg_gradient"
    android:left="1dp" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/check_in_gradient" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

On Marshmallow and above devices the output is: 
[image]

On Lollipop devices the output is: 
[image]

As seen, nothing is shown in Lollipop device, if can anyone guide me what can be wrong in this.
I also tried setting android:background:@null